# Why doesn’t my Flash fallback for HTML5 mp4 video work?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have local html page (html5).
Html - it's one of the bad things i saw.

```
  <video src="kinopoisk2013.mp4" controls>
    <object data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" name="movie"/>
    </object>
  </video>
```

I need that if browser doesn't support mp4 format, he opens this video by HTML. But it does not work, for example in Opera (where I have the Flash player plugin).

How can I make it work? And what is the path I need to write here: `object data="` and `param value="`?

What the difference between Adobe Flash Player and this player http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf and this file .swf?

My adaptiong code by site http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody#notes not works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <body>
    <h1> Flash Video player</h1>
    <p>FIle: kinopoisk2013.mp4</p>

    <video width="640" height="360" controls>
        <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="jwplayer.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="jwplayer.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=kinopoisk2013.png&amp;file=kinopoisk2013.mp4" />
            <img src="kinopoisk2013.png" width="640" height="360" alt="kinopoisk2013"
                 title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
    </video>
    <p> <strong>Download Video:</strong>
        Closed Format:  <a href="kinopoisk2013.mp4">"MP4"</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Video for everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody#video-code).